# SPUtility.GetLocalizedString() Method Parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, resource-files

I have two Label Controls with text property as "Name" and "Company". I want to change the text of these two Controls into Swedish language. For this, I created resource (.resx) file named "MyResource" under mapped folder. How i use this resource file in SPUtility.GetLocalizedString() method ? Can anybody explain about all the parameters used in this method ?  Need one example e.g, with "Name" label Control ?

Comment: [The MSDN entry on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx) explains it quite completely.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                if (web.IsMultilingual)
                {
                    IEnumerable<CultureInfo> cultures = web.SupportedUICultures;
                    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
                    {
                        // Print the value of a language resource in the current language.
                        string str = "$Resources:onet_TeamWebSite";
                        string locStr = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(str, 
                                                                     "core", 
                                                                     (uint)culture.LCID);

                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", culture.Name, locStr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Reference: [SPUtility.GetLocalizedString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx)